Notation for a condition on an infinite series
I would appreciate help in determining whether the following statement makes sense or can be expressed better.
Consider a sequence of positive numbers in descending order $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ where each value of $x_i$ depends on $n$. So, if $n$ changes, we have a different series.  Is there a better way to say: there is a constant $c_n>1$ so that $x_i \rightarrow 0$ for $ i>c_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?
I am trying to say that the number of terms that go to zero increases to infinity as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
I assume specific examples would be, $x_i$ is $O(1/n)$ or $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

If no convergence rate is given, the best way is simply to state $x_n=o(1)$, which simply means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

So what you actually have is an infinite family of positive, decreasing sequences, where for each $n$, sequence number $n$ has $n$ terms, right?

@Arthur, yes, that is correct.

For any value of $~n,~$ although the sequence $~x_1, ~\cdots ~x_n~$ is strictly decreasing, the sequence does not necessarily tend to $~0.~$
A counter-example is
$$x_i = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{i+1}} - \frac{1}{2^{i}} - \cdots - \frac{1}{2^2} > 1 - \frac{1}{2}.$$
So, as $~n \to \infty,~$ in the counter-example, the (infinite sequence) is strictly decreasing, and approaches $~\dfrac{1}{2}~$ from above.

Thanks for the example @user2661923. I indeed want to avoid series like these.
